# Language independent ANTLR grammar for codegen

Tags: parsing, code-generation, antlr

I'm developing an ANTLR grammar to fill in some gaps in text. It's like that:

```
<% SOME_STATEMENT_TO_BE_REPLACED >
```

My problem is, that I have to target multiple languages with ANTLR3's (4 is possible) codegen.
The statement I have to replace is actually a Query for some business logic (there's existing code, I just replace a parser).

I wonder whether I can make use of some features of ANTLR that switch to language templates like:

```
options {
    language=CSharp3;
    output=AST;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}
```

Is there some meta-syntax which I can use across C#, Java and C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some meta-syntax which I can use across C#, Java and C++?

No, there is no such thing in ANTLR. You'll have to do such a replacement yourself.